# Fetch records of single id only not of any other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this...

```
oid      id 
35       1  
43       1  
46       1 
43       2  
49       2
```

I have **id=1** now I want pnly those records which belong to only 1 not any other ids.

i.e o/p - 35,46

I dont need oid = 43 bcz it is belonging to 2 also.

I dont know how to write my question in table on stackoverflow so Please ignore my wrong way of asking.

thanks

Comment: why you dont want id =43 ??

Comment: So basically you want to select rows that are not duplicates (with regards to oid) within the table?

Comment: @sharif because 43 is a duplicate oid in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE id = 1 AND oid NOT IN (SELECT oid FROM `table` where id != 1)
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` may be better

Answer (score 3):

here's another way,

```
SELECT  oid
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY oid
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 1 AND  -- counts the number of ID for OID
        MAX(ID) = 1                 -- checks if the value of ID is equal to 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e876c/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════╗
║ OID ║
╠═════╣
║  35 ║
║  46 ║
╚═════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(oid), oid from table
where id = 1
group by oid
having count(oid) = 1
```

Comment: also I need those records where id = 1.

SO should it be...

select count(id), oid, id from table where id=1
group by id
having count(id) = 1

Comment: @Aquillo Thanks I missed that part

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE id = 1 
AND oid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT oid FROM TABLE_NAME where id != 1)
```